# Angular - test get

Tags: angular, unit-testing, get, jasmine

How i can test this in angular?

```
 get isPerson() {
    return this.persons.some((person) => person === this.personId);
  }
```

I was trying something like this without sucsess:

```
it('should get person', () => {
    const person = new Person('John', 'Doe');
    const spy = spyOnProperty(person, 'isPerson').and.returnValue(
      'john doe'
    );
    expect(person.fullName).toBe('john doe');
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: is this a service or component

Comment: There're few things that, in my opinion, need a fix: isPerson is a boolean getter and you are comparing against an object, then I guess that spyonProperty need a "get" third parameter

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are testing a component, do this

```
it('should get person', () => {
    const person = new Person('John', 'Doe');
    component.person = person
    component.personId = 'John'

    fixture.detectChanges()

 
    expect(component.isPerson).toBeTruthy() 
  });
```